# File validation with fs.stat always fail

Tags: node.js, express

I wrote a little function to validate a path image:

```
var validateImage = function(image) {
  fs.stat('/images/' + image, function(err, stats) {
    if(stats.isFile()) {
      return true;
    }
  });
};
```

It simply checks if the image parameter, that would be something like `"myimage.jpg"` exists under my public/images directory.

I can access the image at:

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/images/myimage.jpg
```

However `validateImage("myimage.jpg")` always return false.

The images directory is under `/public`, which is defined at my app.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `fs.stat` uses the actual path of the file.  Your code is looking for a directory `/images` off the root, which is not how you describe it later.

Comment: also tried validating it with /public/images/ + image. Still nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`'/images/'` is an absolutely path, it will not check inside your public/images directory.

You can make the url relative to your Node scripts by using `__dirname`.

Your directory structure is something like this, it seems

```
root
  public
    images
  app.js
```

You can do this:

```
fs.stat(__dirname + '/public/images/' + image, ...
```